# sending URL in SMS with twilio receiving - 30008 - Unknown error

Tags: php, symfony, twilio, sms

I'm using Twilio in Symfony to send SMS messages.
The SMS message includes an URL

eg.

```
$message = "
Buy soap \n
https://evernote.com/features/notes-app";

/* 
     * 
     * @return Response
     * @throws \Twilio\Exceptions\TwilioException
    */
    public function sendSMS(string $toPhoneNumber, string $message){
        $this->client->messages->create($toPhoneNumber, [
            "body" => $message,
            "from" => $this->twilioNumber
        ]);
    }
```

Every time I append the URL I receive
Error - 30008
Message Delivery - Unknown error

How can I encode the message so I can send the embedded URL?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The code you have shared looks to be correct, so the 30008 error is likely something beyond the sending of the message.

The [Twilio error directory page for error 30008](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30008) gives you a few things to explore to find out what might be going on.

I'd recommend trying to send the message to other numbers, to see if it comes through, and to remove the link, to see if that is causing some sort of carrier filtering. If neither of those makes a difference, check the other reasons on the [error page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30008) and if you still can't send the message, get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact).

Comment: Thank you for your response! I did remove the URL -> the message is sent.  I tried different URL's - the message is not sent. I will follow your advice and try a different number. Does the country number make any difference?

Comment: I don't know if the country number makes a difference I'm afraid. If you can send messages without the URL, then that is clearly the issue here. In your example, the text of your message is rather short. Have you tried sending a longer message that includes a URL?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I finally sent a message to Twilio support and they were very helpful. Sending URLs in the SMS body does depend on the region you are sending ... some regions have filters on these types of messages to avoid sending unsolicited advertising messages. So you have to register your message template including the URLs you are sending and the region - in my case "Nordic countries". I did not finalize this process - but I found the root cause for my problem.